# Error when trying to open up chat pages

Tags: support, chat

I have this problem. Whenever I try to open up the chat pages from the any Stack exchange websites, I get this:

[image]

Well, I thought that it was only happening on ELU. But when I went into Math section and tried to test it by opening it, it gave me same problem. Is it just me? Or is there something wrong with the site?

FYI: I use Windows 7 and IE9.

Comment: Have you cleared your cache?

Answer (score 3):

We can't reproduce this.

(note that the 'break the internet button' is clicked in your browser, that little torn document icon in the address button. I *highly* recommend you turn that off, since it puts IE9 into IE8 emulation mode.)